# Block diagram in tikz, placement of blocks and concatenation of two blocks

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw a block diagram like
[image]

But I am having some difficulties with positioning of the "particle filter" block with respect to "INS" and "RHM", as well as the insertion of the "Height database" block subdivision.

This is what I have so far but I am not sure how to include the centering and the extra sub-block

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm, >=latex', very thick]
    \tikzstyle{block}=[draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=2em, minimum width=2em]
    %\tikzstyle{sum}=[draw, fill=white, circle, node distance=1.5cm]
    \node[
        block,
        ] (ins) {ins};
    \node[
        block,
        below=of ins
        ] (rhm) {RHM};
    
    \draw[->]   (ins)       -|  (pf);
    \draw[->]   (rhm)   --  (pf);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Just a small question: must the two links on the left arrive at the ‘Particle filter’ area, or must the upper link arrive at the upper area and the lower link at the lower area?

Comment: The upper area for both. The lower area is more of a modification to the particle filter block, such that the drawing could have been made without it as well.

Comment: If that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `calc` library, you can position your arrow tips exactly where you want between nodes or even nodes anchors.
With `outer sep=0pt`, and playing with anchors, you can position the *Height database* node exactly beside the *Particle filter* one.
With a particularly well chosen `minimum height`, you can have all blocks the same size, and play with the width when necessary.

[image: Block positioning]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,arrows.meta,positioning,calc,shadows}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=1cm, >=latex', very thick]
        \tikzset{block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=15mm,drop shadow}}
        \node[block] (ins) {INS};
        \node[block, below=of ins] (rhm) {RHM};
        \node[block,outer sep=0pt,minimum width=3cm,right=2cm of $(ins)!.5!(rhm)$](pf){Particle filter};
        \node[block,outer sep=0pt,  minimum width=3cm,anchor=north] (hd) at (pf.south) {Height database}; 
        \draw[->]   (ins.east) --++ (.5,0) |- ($(pf.north west)!0.25!(pf.south west)$);
        \draw[->]   (rhm.east)  --++ (.5,0) |- ($(pf.north west)!0.75!(pf.south west)$);;
        \draw[->]   (pf.east)  --++ (1,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: added the drop shadow, even if it was not explicitly asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
Ups, by accident I upload my testbed not only solution. Now this is corrected, present is only MWE concerning OP problem. It is simple and concise:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,
                positioning,
                shadows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 1cm and 1cm,
 block/.style = {draw, fill=white, drop shadow,
                 minimum height=7mm, minimum width=#1,
                 outer sep=0pt},
 block/.default = 4em
                    ]
\node[block] (ins) {INS};
\node[block, below=of ins] (rhm) {RHM};
\node[block=8em, right=of $(ins.east)!0.5!(rhm.east)$] (pf) {particle filter};
\node[block=8em, below=0pt of pf] (hd) {Height database};
%
\draw   (ins.east) -- ++ (0.5,0) |-  ([yshift=+1mm] pf.west)
        (rhm.east) -- ++ (0.5,0) |-  ([yshift=-1mm] pf.west)
        (pf.east)  -- ++ (0.5,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @Morten Nissov, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

To give you some more options of optimising the zig-zag arrows, you can use a slight variation of the notation to use positioning relative to the actual node positions rather than defining them using the `++` notation.

Also, you can use the `(pf.<angle>)` notation instead of calculating the position at the right-hand side of the pf node:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary {positioning, calc,shadows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance=1.2cm, >=stealth, thick,
        block/.style={draw, fill=white, rectangle, minimum height=4em, minimum width=4em,align=center,font=\sffamily,drop shadow}]
        \node[block] (ins) {INS};
        \node[block,below=of ins] (rhm) {RHM};
        
        \node[block, minimum width=8em, below right= of ins,yshift=1cm] (pf) {Particle filter};
        \node[block, minimum width=8em, below= 0pt of pf,yshift=.9pt] {Height database};
        
        \draw[->]  (ins) -- ($(ins)!.4!(ins -| pf)$) |- (pf.170);
        \draw[->]  (rhm) -- ($(rhm)!.4!(rhm -| pf)$) |- (pf.190);
        \draw (pf.east) -- ++(.5,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Also, the other answers kind of ignored the `drop shadow`.

[image]